# Are all irreducible representations of solvable Lie algebras 1-dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a solvable Lie algebra. By Lie's theorem, it is easy to see that any finite dimensional irreducible representation is 1 dimensional. Is it possible to remove the condition that the representation be finite dimensional?

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~reb/courses/261/11.pdf claims that the answer is no, but I don't know an example.

Comment: Consider the Weyl algebra $W$. It doesn't even have any nontrivial finite-dimensional representations $V$, since then we'd have $\operatorname{tr}_V 1 = \operatorname{tr}_V[\partial, X] = 0$. Take a suitable subalgebra of $W$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link given by Qiaochu Yuan contains a counterexample if you remove finite dimensional. Consider the 3-dimensional Lie algebra (over a field $k$) generated by $x$, $d/dx$ and $1$. This is a nilpotent Lie algebra (hence solvable), with $1$ central and
$$[d/dx,x]=1.$$
This Lie algebra acts on the polynomial ring $k[x]$ without eigenvalues. In fact, the enveloping algebra of this Lie algebra is the Heisenberg algebra, $H$, and $k[x]$ is a faithful irreducible $H$-module.